# Does firebug make firefox slow for browsing?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firebug

Does firebug make firefox slow for browsing?

Answer (score 4):

The older version made it considerably slower on Javascript heavy web pages (such as Gmail), however, I have not noticed anything on the latest version.

As far as I know, with the latest version, when you have it set to disabled on a site (so the logo is grey), I do not notice any speed difference to not having it installed at all.

Comment: firebug does slowdown the page, but newer versions have it disabled by default, and now it's actually tied to individual tabs, so it's not really an issue anymore.    You can always start a new profile in mozilla and switch between the two to do your testing.   just execute `firefox.exe --profile-manager`